# Uploading large files with REST api in Laravel to Amazon S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload videos to an Amazon S3 bucket through my Laravel API.
I'm using the Laravel filesystem, and using:

```
Storage::getDriver()
         ->putStream('videos/' . $fileName . '.' . $ext, fopen($file, 'r+'));
```

It works perfectly for mp4 files of 1Mb, but when i try to upload something like 30Mb mp4 file, it takes about 3 minutes, and it doesn't succeed.

I use Postman to send the request POST http://localhost:8000/api/videos with Content-Type: form-data.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: For large files, AWS Multipart Upload is the way to go: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/sdksupportformpu.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution to the problem was to set a higher value for "upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size" in my php.ini file.
Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: find the "php.ini" file (/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini) and open it by root (sudo)

Secondly: change post_max_size=50M and upload_max_filesize=50M (in your case just need to change upload_max_filesize).